# How to run a map of runnables in order

Tags: java, lambda, runnable

I'm trying to make a method that runs a series of steps defined by lambdas. Each of those steps can be anything, they will be defined in different parts of the code, but they share some logic that has to be run before and after the lambda. Also, they have a string which defines their name.

The following code illustrates how I am doing it. Since I haven't created a class for these `Step` (to avoid the need of calling to a constructor every time I create one of them), I've tried to use a `Map<String, CheckedRunnable>`. However, the steps aren't executed in order. I thought about using a `LinkedHashMap` instead of `Map` as the method argument, but the lambdas says `Target type of a lambda conversion must be an interface`.

(Checked runnable is from `net.jodah.failsafe.function.CheckedRunnable`, is just [A Runnable that throws checked exceptions](https://javadoc.io/static/net.jodah/failsafe/1.0.3/net/jodah/failsafe/function/CheckedRunnable.html))

```java
import net.jodah.failsafe.function.CheckedRunnable;

import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    static void runSomeStuff(Map<String, CheckedRunnable> actions){
        actions.forEach((name, action) -> {
            // run something before running each step
            // ...
            System.out.println("Running " + name + "...");
            try {
                action.run(); // execute the lambda
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            // run something after running each step
            // ...
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runSomeStuff(Map.of(
                // "Step 1" is a custom name for the set of instructions that will be executed
                "Step 1", () -> {
                    System.out.println("1"); // custom logic, print only for illustration
                },
                // Same as Step 1, it could be anything
                "Step 2", () -> {
                    System.out.println("2");
                }
                ));
    }
}
```

Another option is to create a class and use a `List`, which works, but, as I mentioned before, adds the need to call a constructor each time you define a new step:

```java
import net.jodah.failsafe.function.CheckedRunnable;

import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    static class Substep{
        String name;
        CheckedRunnable runnable;
        Substep(String name, CheckedRunnable runnable){
            this.name = name;
            this.runnable = runnable;
        
    }

    static void runSomeStuff(List<Substep> actions){
        actions.forEach((substep) -> {
            // run something before running each step
            // ...
            System.out.println("Running " + substep.name + "...");
            try {
                substep.runnable.run(); // execute the lambda
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            // run something after running each step
            // ...
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runSomeStuff(List.of(
                new Substep("Step 1", () -> { // "Step 1" is a custom name for the set of instructions that will be executed
                    System.out.println("1"); // custom logic, print only for illustration
                }),
               new Substep("Step 2", () -> { // Same as Step 1, it could be anything
                    System.out.println("2"); // custom logic, print only for illustration
                }
                )));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are these things in a map in the first place? Why not put them in a list?

Comment: Can you show your attempt of using a linked hash map?

Comment: They are in a map because I need to provide a name for the steps but I didn't want to create a class for it in order to avoid more boilerplate code. Even though, as you said, If I do that and use a List, I can run them in the correct order

Comment: What is `CheckedRunnable` and which line produces this compilation error `Target type of a lambda conversion must be an interface` ?

Comment: `CheckedRunnable` is a runnable interface of Java, like a `Runnable`, which runs the code provided in the lambda and checks for throwables.

If I change `Map` for `LinkedHashMap` in the declartion of `runSomeStuff()`, all the lambdas in the method call produce the error

Comment: Because with a simple `Map` the execution order is broken. What I'm trying to do is to have a list of lambdas, each one with a string name linked to it, avoiding the creation of a class for them (because I don't want to call a constructor method for each lambda I define)

Comment: "avoid the creation of a class", "avoid more boilerplate"... by my experience avoiding to create a class (that would better represent the data) is almost the opposite - more *headache* and difficulties, and you end up messing up more... No idea what exactly `CheckedRunnable` (not standard Java) but rest of posted code works with a `LinkedHashMap` (the creation and populating of the map must be adapted)

Comment: I con only agree with @user16320675: it's the essence of OO to invent and use good abstractions. And a `record` is close to zero boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, as mentioned in the comments, `List` is a semantically more appropriate mean of storing the data because you're not accessing values through their keys, but simply iterating over the map entries.

Instead of using a map in order to fuse the two attributes together the intuitive and maintainable way of structure the data would be to define a custom object. Since Java 16 [records](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html) it might be literally done with a single line of code.

```
record Action(String name, Runnable task) {}

List<Action> actions = List.of(
    new Action("Step 1", () -> System.out.println(1)),
    new Action("Step 2", () -> System.out.println(2))
);
```

But if you're convinced that you need a Map, in case if these tasks are as simple as you've described, you can generate using a plain index-based loop or a stream.

```
final int actionCount = 3;
        
Map<String, CheckedRunnable> actionByStepName = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, actionCount)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        i -> "Step " + i,
        i -> () -> System.out.println(i),
        (left, right) -> {
            throw new AssertionError("duplicated keys are not expected");
        },
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```